# javascript multi regular expression

Tags: javascript, regex, preg-match

I have the following string in java script

```
stringsda="http://site.com/colours/2543 http://site.com/colours/5543 http://site.com/colours/9435";
```

I need to get the value 2543,5543 and 9453  from the above string **stringsda**.with the following code i can retrieve 1st one **2543** only...how can i retrieve the next two values **(9435 and 5543)**

```
patt1 = /colours\/(\d+)"/;
var a=(stringsda.match(patt1)[1]);
alert(a);
```

a  alerts **2543** ,,i need other two values too

Comment: `a` cannot show `2543`, because `stringsda` does not contain `apps`. Can you post real code, which you have tested? The first lines are syntactically invalid.

Comment: i have editted...the above code works

Comment: This is your code: http://jsfiddle.net/9fFdC/, which certainly doesn't work correctly. The quotes are unterminated, the words/pattern don't match.

Comment: Do you mean that stringsda is equal to the string "http://site.com/colours/2543 http://site.com/colours/5543 http://site.com/colours/9435" ?  I don't think you can have double quotes inside double quotes without a slash (i.e. "foo\"bar")

Comment: You can't describe multiline strings like that in JavaScript.

Comment: yea...u can assume like that. ... i retrieve a page source and above code works for me...but it extracts only first regex..i need remaining two

Comment: @RobW : my first value is retrived successfully...how can i retrieve second value again ?

Answer (score 3):

Assuming that your input is:

```
var stringsda="http://site.com/colours/2543 \
http://site.com/colours/5543 \
http://site.com/colours/9435";
```

The desired output can be obtained by using the global flag. There are several methods to accomplish the goal, the following being one of them:

```
var output = stringsda.match(/\/colours\/\d+/g).join('/').match(/\d+/g);
```

### Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/9fFdC/3/

Comment: Note that this matches *all* numbers. If you want to only match numbers after a "colours" bit you need to match for "/colours\/(\d+)/" and then remove the extra "colour" from the matched strings.

Comment: @missingno In the comments on the question, I asked whether the string contained numbers besides the desired ones. His answer was "no".

Comment: i have the regular expression...i just want each values in seperate variables... and i need to retrieve the second and third values

Comment: @JustinBiaber `output` in my answer is an array of all matched numbers, ie `["2543", "5543", "9435"]`. To get the first number, use `output[0]`, second: `output[1]`, third: `output[2]`, etc.

Comment: @RobW : yea it works...but i need preg match with string of colours/2543 ,,cos i may have other numbers in string too